# Javascript usage during ajax code

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm renewing question. For simplify situation I've this script in **index.php** file

```
<form name="f" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="button" name="but" id="but" value="Retrieve">
    <div id="div"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="ok">
</form>



<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("but").onclick = function(){
    var http = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
    }
    if (http){
        http.open("POST","other.php",true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (http.status==200 && http.readyState==4){
                document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = http.responseText;
            }
        };
        http.send(null);
    }
};
document.getElementById("y").onclick = function(){
    alert("okaaay");
};
</script>
```

And have **other.php** file with the script below

```
<?php
echo "<input type='text' name='y' id='y'>";
?>
```

Ajax script works just nice, but my problem is that when this marked input element is retrieved in index.php page , with second JavaScript code I can't manipulate it , please help , thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the code so you set the "y" onclick after the response from the other.php comes back, like so:

```
 http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (http.status==200 && http.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = http.responseText;
            document.getElementById("y").onclick = function(){
              alert("okaaay");
            };
        }
    };
```

otherwise you're setting that event handler on an element that does not yet exist :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should, instead, just send back some information:

```
$response = json_encode( array('type'=>'text','name'=>'y','id'=>'y') );
print $response;
```

Then when you receive it (as type application/json), use javascript to create a new element of type `input`, and then give it your desired properties using the json you received. Once its created and stored in a variable, place that element inside your div.